# Какие технологии поддерживает GitHub Pages?

Tags: github

В общем, такое дело: хочу создать себе сайт на GitHub Pages. Тут есть 2 варианта: генераторы контента или HTML страницы. На одном HTML, сами понимаете, сложно делать сайт с частыми обновлениями: копировать шаблон и все такое. Хочется автоматизации. Готовые генераторы контента мне не понравились. Какой не попробую - возникает какая-то проблема.

Поэтому решил собрать себе сам простенький генератор, который будет на localhost markdown -> HTML переводить, а на GitHub к этим файлам контента подключать шаблон. Так вот, какие технологии поддерживает GitHub Pages, через которые можно реализовать подключение шаблона? Хотя бы SSI? Или только HTML?

Comment: [вот вроде](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/)

Comment: там только стандартные шаблоны возможны

Comment: В результате исследований оказалось, что SSI нету (что уж говорить о языках программирования). Пришлось обойтись фреймами. Да, я знаю, все их не любят, но другого способа пока нету. Поэтому я все еще очень жду и надеюсь, что мне кто-нибудь скажет, как использовать на GitHub Pages языки программирования, если это реально.

Comment: github это не халявный хостинг для ваших сайтов. из языков как не трудно догадаться поддерживается javascript. сам github не будет выполнять ваш код, для этого есть heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По состоянию на 2015 год - никакие.

Есть два обходных пути:

1. Локальный север

   - завести локальный http-сервер, на нём пользоваться любыми
     технологиями
   - на этот http-сервер нацеливать кравлер, который сохранит весь сайт в виде html
   - полученные html закачивать в ветку gh-pages
2. Бесплатный хостинг

   то же самое, что выше, но не нужно запускать сервер локально