# Github.io php поддерживает?

Tags: php, github

Добрый день!
Подскажите, где можно почитать о том, что поддерживает github.io? Сделал простенький проект, но как ни стараюсь, форму отправки e-mail сделать не могу: такое чувство, что php не поддерживается. Может, знаете какие-то обходные пути?

Comment: [jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/) - можно использовать, в остальном - это статический сайт

Comment: Помимо javascript языки программирования не поддерживаются. [Обход](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433310/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: нашел уже это, буду разбираться..
GitHub pages does limit you to using static assets (HTML, CSS and JS) for your websites, but you could use something like Jekyll to make it easier to generate these files.
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website

Answer (score 7):

**GitHub pages** используется для создания только *статичных* сайтов.